# Iterating a Hashmap : Incompatible types

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

I got a HashMap and want to iterate it. But somehow it is saying that I have incompatible types.

```
Required: java.util.Map.Entry <java.lang.String , java.lang.String>
 Found : java.lang.Object
```

Heres my code :

```
 Map hashmapMessagesKey = new HashMap<String,String>();
 for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashmapMessagesKey.entrySet()) {

  }
```

Comment: Your Map is currently a raw type, use Map<String,String> instead of Map.

Answer (score 2):

The declared type of your variable is the deciding factor, not the initialization. Your declared type is currently a raw Map-type but should be generic:

```
Map<String, String> hashmapMessagesKey = new HashMap<>();
```

Besides, depending on your use-case, the for-each method might be more readable as you can name the key and value instead of using entry.getKey() and entry.getValue():

```
hashmapMessagesKey.forEach((key, value) -> {
    // loop body
});
```

Comment: I see. Imo the error code is a bit misleading. Thank you ! I will accept your Answer

Answer (score 1):

Your map defination seems to be wrong.

```
Map<String, String> map= new HashMap<String, String>();
```